# MediaPlayer plays my MP3 files but really quiet

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an old Android app, targeted for SDK16, which played my own MP3 sounds loud and clear:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

if (mp != null) {
    mp.reset();
    mp.release();
}
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.red_click);
mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
mp.start();
```

I haven't done any Android coding for a few years, and now I started to work on my old project again, but now targeted to SDK23.  I didn't change my code from the one above.  Now my sounds are still playing in the app, but really really quiet.

I tried to search for an answer but couldn't find any: what has changed in MP implementation from SDL16, and how should I play my files now such that I get the full volume for them?

Comment: Don't you just use different devices? The old one just was louder itself? Or the music channel volume is set to quiet?

Comment: All volumes are set to maximum on the phone.  All other sounds are really loud.

Comment: Have you tried playing same file using different player?

Comment: This page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html shows the state diagram for the MediaPlayer.  From it I get a hint that I should somehow prepare() my player before setting the volumes for the left and right channels?

Comment: maibe, but AFAIK it is set to `1.0f` by default

Comment: Omg, this indeed was a user error - my MP3 files were not normalised, and they actually were really quiet. Had to use Audacity to normalise them.  Glad to know MP still works as before.